# プライマリキーのカラムを取得し、値を結合したカラムを作成したい

Tags: mysql, sql

MySQLについて質問です。

テーブルの主キーを取得し、値を結合したカラムを追加するということを1回のクエリで実現したいです。

以下のようなテーブルがあったとして、プライマリキーが'id'と'client_id'の2つだったとします。

```
+------+-----------+-------+
| id   | client_id | name  |
+------+-----------+-------+
| A001 |         1 | userA |
| A002 |         2 | userB |
+------+-----------+-------+
```

プライマリキーの内容をカンマ区切りで結合した'result'というカラムを追加したいです。

```
+------+-----------+-------+---------+
| id   | client_id | name  | result  |
+------+-----------+-------+---------+
| A001 |         1 | userA | A001,1  |
| A002 |         2 | userB | A002,2  |
+------+-----------+-------+---------+
```

2回のクエリでの実装は以下の手順で行えましたが、1クエリで実現する方法をご教授いただきたいです。

1. INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNSからプライマリキーのリストを取得
2. 1で取得したプライマリキーからテーブルをSELECTするSQLを構築、CONCAT_WS関数でresultカラムを作成

以上です。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 多分、2回クエリを実行するしかないと思います。

Comment: テーブル設計としてカラム内容を把握していない前提でしょうか？ 一般的にはテーブル設計を把握しているべきであり、INFORMATION_SCHEMAを参照することなくSQLを記述できるはずなのですが。

Comment: はい、その通りカラムの内容は把握出来ておらず、プライマリキー情報も不明です。将来的に、新規で作成されるテーブルに対しても動作するように、既存のテーブル設計にとらわれない実装をしなければならない状態です。

Comment: 1回のクエリで実現したい理由は何なのでしょうか？
質問の2. のSQL作成を人力でやりたくないということであれば、複数のクエリを一括で流して、動的SQLを使えば実現できそうな気がします。

Comment: SQLはスクリプト言語から実行を行うのですが、実行速度を重視しなければならず、一度プライマリキーを取得したのちに、もう一度スクリプト側でSQLを組み立てて、実行するのは非効率かと思い、1度で実現する方法を模索していた次第でした。